# Why is my ISO datetime string with timezone converting the time upon POST?

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, rest

I am POSTing a JSON object as a string to a service method via the fetch API. Some of the properties in the object are ISO 8601 strings with timezones (e.g. "StartDate": "2019-04-16T13:46:04-06:00"). That is what the string looks like before POSTing via the fetch API. 
The C# REST service method that I am posting to has only ([FromBody]object document) as the parameter. Upon getting to that method, the string looks like this: "StartDate": "2019-04-16T19:46:04+00:00".

Why/where is the timezone getting converted? It was a string upon POSTing to the service and is still a string there.

Something to note: this works fine when using the service locally (via localhost). When it is deployed, it does not work.

Example code (TypeScript, client-side):

```
    postDocument() {
        let doc = "{'StartDate': '2019-04-16T13:46:04-06:00'}";
        let response = await fetch("[serviceURL]/api/Document/AddDocument", 
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: doc
        });
    }
```

Example code (server-side (in TestService), C#):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddDocument([FromBody]object document)
    {
        // Datetime string has already been converted, no longer has timezone.
        console.log(document.ToString()); 
        // startdate here is = "2019-04-16T19:46:04+00:00"
        return;//Doesn't matter what's in this method
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not the toString() method which converts it, rather than the Post or the model binder? There's an extra step here that you haven't accounted for. And why aren't you using a strongly typed viewmodel instead of "object" - normally the way you've got it now will make it very difficult to access individual fields in the input when it arrives on the server

Comment: Anyway, if the result is different in one environment than another, then usually the code is not directly at fault. Instead look for relevant differences in the environment. In this case, checking the timezone settings on the server, and comparing that to the setting on the local machine is likely to be relevant, for example

Comment: @ADyson it ended up being the default Json serialization settings doing it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these lines to the Register method of my WebApiConfig in App_Start forced my service to not parse the DateTime and therefore it kept the timezone.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateParseHandling.None;
}
```